# How would I limit per day usage for user with standard access rights to X minutes on macos 10.15?

Tags: macos, screen-time

I have account with administrative access on home computer, naturally.
How would I trim to family member with standard rights usage to 30 minutes per day on macOS 10.15 (in screen time or whatever.)

UPD20210407 I've filed FB9071215 with Apple to untether that functionality
from family sharing setting.

Comment: So you want to limit the screen time for users on your laptop who don't have iCloud accounts?

Comment: Yes.!! Exactly.

Comment: Could you make iCloud accounts for the other family members and set up family sharing in this way?

Comment: I suppose I should try, currently have no time as this is significant amount of work creating e-mails etc.

Comment: It isn't that much work. As listed here (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201084#create), you can create a child account without needing individual email addresses for each child.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to [create child iCloud accounts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201084#create) for each of the individual users.